# Determinants of symmetric tridiagonal matrix and of Toeplitz matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

Is there any fast way to compute the determinant of this matrix:

$$ \begin{vmatrix}
a & b & 0 &0 &0 \\
b & a & b &0 &0 \\
0 & b & a &b &0 \\
0 & 0 & b &a &b \\
0 & 0 & 0 &b &a \end{vmatrix} $$

And can you say anything about 
$$
\frac{det(M_{k+1})}{det(M_{k})}
$$

where $M_{k}$ is a toeplitz matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $T_n$ is the determinant for $n$x$n$ matrix, then we have by expanding using the first row  (and first column in the second matrix) that

$$T_n = a T_{n-1} - b^2 T_{n-2}$$

with $T_1 = a$ and $T_2 = a^2 - b^2$.

You should now be able to compute a closed form easily, using the characteristic equation.

Comment: Can you please explain how you got this recurrence function?

Comment: @neticin: See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeterminantExpansionbyMinors.html. We pick the first row to get two minors, in the second minor, we pick the first column.

Answer (score 3):

See the paper [Analytical Inversion of Symmetric Tridiagonal Matrices](http://www.phys.lsu.edu/~amarti9/adfaerf/241.%20Analytical%20Inversion%20of%20Symmetric%20Tridiagonal%20Matrices.pdf), and in particular the formulas (6) and (7).  To apply this it is only necessary to remove a factor of $b$ from each row of your matrix, with the accompanying factor of $b^n$ from the determinant.

Of course if $b = 0$...