# How to calculate the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

$$\begin{vmatrix}
x & y & a & a & \dots & a & a & a\\
y & x & y & a & \dots & a & a & a\\
a & y & x & y & \dots & a & a & a\\
a & a & y & x & \dots & a & a & a\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
a & a & a & a& \dots & x & y & a\\
a & a & a & a & \dots & y & x & y\\
a & a & a & a & \dots & a & y & x
\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: i have tried two ways, such as recurrence relation, but it's not easy to write, and partition into (n+1) determinant, but the n determinants among them have no similar characteristics.

Comment: have you tried calculating these determinants for nxn matrices for small n?

Comment: yes, but i can't find anything useful for the general case.

Comment: $x$, $x^2-y^2$, $-a^2 x + 2 a y^2 + x^3 - 2 x y^2$, $a^4 - 2 a^3 y - 3 a^2 x^2 + 4 a^2 x y - a^2 y^2 + 4 a x y^2 - 2 a y^3 + x^4 - 3 x^2 y^2 + y^4$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this determinant has a nice closed form. However, you might find the following approach to be helpful.

We can write the matrix $A$ of interest as a rank-1 update of a [tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal-Toeplitz-Matrix). Write $A = T + axx^\top$, where
$$
T = \pmatrix{x-a & y-a & 0\\y-a & x-a & y-a\\
&y-a & \ddots & \ddots\\
&&\ddots&&y-a\\
&&&y-a&x-a}, \quad x = \pmatrix{1\\1\\\vdots\\ 1}.
$$
Per the linked wikipedia page, we can express the determinant of $T$ as the product of its eigenvalues, which is to say that
$$
\det(T) = \prod_{k=1}^n \left(x-a + |y-a| \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{n+1} \right) \right).
$$
Alternatively, the determinant of $T$ can be described by a recurrence, as explained in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/107559/81360) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/266998/81360).

From there, $\det(A)$ can be computed with the help of the [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma). In particular, we have
$$
\det(A) = (1 + a\cdot x^\top T^{-1}x)\det(T).
$$
Notably, $T^{-1}$ has the closed form that is [described here](https://www.phys.lsu.edu/%7Eamarti9/adfaerf/241.%20Analytical%20Inversion%20of%20Symmetric%20Tridiagonal%20Matrices.pdf) (among other places). $x^\top T^{-1}x$ is the sum of all entries of $T^{-1}$.